# Does BizTalk Server support exchanging large files over Azure File Shares when 3rd Party system is using the REST API?

Tags: biztalk, azure-files

> "Starting with BizTalk Server 2016, you can connect to an Azure file
>   share using the File adapter. The Azure storage account must be
>   mounted on your BizTalk Server."
>
> source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configure-the-file-adapter

So at first glance, this would appear to be a supported thing to do.  And until recently, we have been using Azure File Shares with BizTalk Server with no problems.  However, we are now looking to exchange larger files (approx 2 MB).  BizTalk Server is consuming the files without any errors but the file contains only NUL bytes. (The message in the tracking database is the correct size but is filled with NUL bytes).

The systems writing the files (Azure Logic Apps, Azure Storage Explorer) are seeing the following error:

```
{
  "status": 409,
  "message": "The specified resource may be in use by an SMB client.\r\nclientRequestId: 4e0085f6-4464-41b5-b529-6373fg9affb0",
}
```

If we try uploading the file to the mounted drive using Windows Explorer (thus using the SMB protocol), the file is picked up without problems by BizTalk Server.

As such, I suspect the BizTalk Server File adapter is not supported when the system writing or consuming the file is using the REST API rather than the SMB protocol.

**So my questions are:**

- Is this a caveat to BizTalk Server support of Azure File Share that is documented somewhere?
- Is there anything we can do to make this work?
- Or do we just have to use a different way of exchanging files?

We have unsuccessfully investigated/tried the following:

- I cannot see any settings in the Azure File Storage connector (as
  used by Logic Apps) that would ensure files are locked till they are
  fully written.
- Tried using the File adapter advanced adapter property “rename files while reading”, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried writing the files with a temporary filename that does not match the file mask on the file receive?

Comment: @charlie.mott : Azure File Storage connector is still in preview. But anyway, did you closely check if the file has a different extension when the connector is writing the file? Maybe you have to let biztalk only pick up files with a certain file extension. Your other option could be to let some connector rename the file after writing is done, so you only pick up files that are renamed to something familiar.

Comment: I understand that we could ask the 3rd Party to rename the file after it has finished writing it.  But I would prefer to change the protocol than ask the 3rd Party to do this.

Comment: p.s. there is no Rename File action with the Azure File Storage connector (as used by Logic Apps). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/.  I assume if we used the "Copy File" action we would hit the same problem.

Comment: We have also considered the signal file pattern (http://kentweare.blogspot.com/2008/01/processing-inter-dependent-files-using.html).  However, again, we would prefer to switch to a different protocol rather than build this into the logic app and build either a custom adapter or orchestration logic in BizTalk.  The question remains, can we get BizTalk to work with Azure File Shares without building rename or signal file pattern logic?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [SFTP-SSH connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh#compare-sftp-ssh-versus-sftp). It does message chunking with a total file size of 1 GB or smaller and: `Provides the Rename file action, which renames a file on the SFTP server.`!!

With an ISE environment you could potentially leverage a [total file size of 5B](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/integration-service-environments-ise-are-now-generally-available/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution we have implemented with justifications for this choice.

**Chosen Option:  We stuck with Azure File Shares and implemented the signal file pattern**

- The Logic Apps of the integrated system writes a signal file to the same folder where the message file is created. The signal file has the same filename but with a .done extension.  e.g. myfile.json.done.
- In the BizTalk solution, a custom pipeline component has be written to retrieve the related message file for the signal file.
- Note: Concern that the Azure Files connector is still in preview.

**Discounted Option 1: Logic Apps use the BizTalk Server connector**

- Whilst this would work, I was keen to keep a layer of separation between the system and BizTalk.  This allows BizTalk applications to be deployed without downtime of the endpoints to system.
- Restricts the load levelling (throttling) capabilities of BizTalk Server.  Note: we have a [custom file adapter](http://mstravi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/custom-file-adapter-for-pooling-interval.html) to restrict the rate that files are picked up.
- This option also requires setup of the “On-Premise Data Gateway”.

**Discounted Option 2: Use of File System connector**

- Logic Apps writes the file in chunks of 2MB and then releases the lock on the file.  This enables BizTalk to pick up the file instantly. When the connector tries to write the next chunk of 2MB, the file is not available anymore and hence fails with a 400 status error "The requested action could not be completed. Check your request parameters to make sure the path //test.json' exists on your file system.”
- File sizes are limited to 20MB.
- Required setup of On-Premise Data Gateway.  Note: We also considered this to be a good time to also introduce use of Integration Service Environment (ISE) to host Logic Apps within the vNET.  The thinking is that this would keep File exchanges between the system and BizTalk within the network.  However, currently there is [no ISE specific connector for the File System](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/37935262-ise-specific-connector-for-file-system).

**Discounted Option 3: Use of SFTP connector**

- Our expectation is that logic apps using FTP will experience similar chunking issues while Logic Apps is writing files.
- The Azure SFTP connector has no rename action.
- We were keen to avoid use of this ageing protocol.
- We were keen to avoid extra infrastructure and software needed to support SFTP.

**Discounted Option 4: Logic Apps Renames the File once written**

- There is no rename action in the [File Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/file-service-rest-api) or File Connector.  Only a Copy action.  Our concern Copy is the file still needs time to be written so the same chunking problem remains.

**Discounted Option 5: Logic Apps use of Service Bus Connector**

- The [maximum size of a message is 1MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas).

**Discounted Option 6: Using Azure File Sync to Mirror files to another location.**

- The File Sync only happens once every 24 hours, as such was not suitable for our integration needs.  Microsoft are [planning to build change notifications into Azure File Shares](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/33072151-enable-immediate-sync-after-changes-on-the-azure-f) to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have just announced "**Azure Service Bus premium tier namespaces now support sending and receiving message payloads up to 100 MB (up from 1MB previously)**."

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-service-bus-large-message-support-reaches-general-availability/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging#large-messages-support